# Have you ever been OR Have you ever?

Tags: passive-voice

Which question is right?

> Have you ever been had a bomb alert?

or

> Have you ever had a bomb alert?

Comment: These two questions are from the test. Need to choose only 1 without any changes. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version would be "Have you ever had a bomb alert"

if you were to say "Have you ever BEEN had a bomb alert" it would come off as incredibly confusing to English speakers.

For example

> "He had been in trouble" vs
>   "He had in trouble"

In that situation "He had been in trouble would be the correct usage, the reason is that you can "be" in trouble whereas you cannot "be" in a bomb alert.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what the question means. It might mean **have you been involved in a bomb alert** or **has there been a bomb alert**.

We frequent use the expression **been in** to mean **experienced** or **been involved in**.

> Have you ever been in a fire drill?
>   Have you ever been in cycle race?
>   Have you ever been in a police chase?
>   Have you ever been in a traffic accident.

These constructions are perfectly idiomatic.

On the other hand, for example, a policeman might receive a call to the effect that there had been a bomb scare at a building. The policeman might inquire of the receptionist: **Have you had a bomb alert**, meaning **have you been alerted to a bomb**.

It is hard to know which situation the examiner had in mind as both answers are possible. But in practice, the second scenario is more likely than the first.